# TreeMap put is not working as expected

Tags: java, object, treemap

```
class Point{
    int x, y, l;

    Point(int x, int y, int l){
        this.x =x;
        this.y =y;
        this.l=l;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Point)) return false;
        Point p = (Point) obj;
        return this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y;
    }
}

    TreeMap<Point,Integer>  sortedMap = new TreeMap<>((p1, p2)-> p1.l-p2.l);
    sortedMap.put(new Point(4,5,0),0);
    sortedMap.put(new Point(5,5,0),6);
    System.out.println(sortedMap.size()); -> Output:  1
    System.out.println((new Point(4,5,0)).equals(new Point(5,5,0))); -> Output -> False.
```

I have overloaded both hashcode, equals method in class. I think put method should use equals method to determine whether the same object exits or not. But it is not working as expected.

**I am not sure why my hashMap size is 1.** Please let me know if I understood hashmap working wrongly. Help me to identify bug in this code ?

Comment: Why is your equality check `p1.l - p2.l`?

Comment: Why are you calling your variable `sortedSet` when it's not a set but a map?

Comment: @MuratK.: That's not an equality check - it's an ordering.

Comment: @Aubin: That's still a valid `hashCode` implementation for the given `equals` method. Yes, it'll give the same hash code for multiple equal values, but that's fine. (It would potentially cause inefficiencies, but it's valid.)

Comment: The tags say [tag:hashmap], but your code says `TreeMap` - which is correct?

Answer (score 11):

Your `TreeMap` is comparing `Point` values by the `l` part (whatever that's meant to be). That's what this part of your code does:

```
new TreeMap<>((p1, p2)-> p1.l-p2.l);
```

The two points you've created have the same `l` value (0) so they're considered equal... so the second call to `put` replaces the existing entry. `TreeMap` doesn't use `equals` and `hashCode` at all.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.

Your comparison *isn't* consistent with `equals`, which is why you're seeing results which violate the `Map` contract.

Comment: *Or* `Comparator.comparingInt(Point::l)`

Comment: @Eugene indeed, but that takes up more screen space.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou is that *ever* an argument? this is doing the correct thing, by not using boxing/un-boxing all the time

Answer (score 6):

`TreeMap` only uses the supplied `Comparator` (or the natural ordering when available) to determine equality, so `equals` and `hashCode` make no difference.

In your case, both `Point`s have the same `l` value, so they are considered identical according to your `Comparator`.

You can modify your `Comparator` to take all the properties (`l`, `x` and `y`) into account when determining the order (and the equality) of your keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
sortedSet.put(new Point(4,5,0),0);
sortedSet.put(new Point(5,5,0),6);
```

These put call's use the supplied comparator `((p1, p2)-> p1.l-p2.l)` to check if two Points are `equal`.

```
(new Point(4,5,0)).equals(new Point(5,5,0))
```

This uses the equals overridden in `Point` class.

Hence the difference..